# problems installing pyffmpeg on mac os x

Tags: python, macos, cython, failed-installation

I'm having some troubling installing pyffmpeg (https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) on mac os X lion. It doesn't list dependencies anywhere, I figured out it needs cython after playing around a bit. I installed cython via easy_install which was ok. But it gives compilation errors when I try to install. Log is pasted below (removed, but it's still on pyffmpeg message board).

It's probably nothing magical, but I'm not getting it. Could it be that cython has the wrong version?

UPDATE: I'm a little bit further in, I think I was missing some libs, I still get stuck, now on the compilation, the output is pasted below, also in the message board of pyffmpeg (https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/issues/detail?id=44).

```
    sampa:pyffmpeg-2.1beta alex$ sudo python setup.py install
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    cythoning pyffmpeg.pyx to pyffmpeg.c
    warning: pyffmpeg.pyx:1904:49: Unreachable code

    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
    ##################################################################



    def py_av_register_all():
        if __registered:
                      ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    pyffmpeg.pyx:705:19: local variable '__registered' referenced before assignment
    building 'pyffmpeg' extension
    C compiler: llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe

    compile options: '-I/opt/ffmpeg/include -I/usr/include/ffmpeg -I./include -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_e2af7b7_20110721-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'
    llvm-gcc-4.2: pyffmpeg.c
    pyffmpeg.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
    pyffmpeg.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccXZr5zV.out (No such file or directory)
    pyffmpeg.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
    pyffmpeg.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccXZr5zV.out (No such file or directory)
    error: Command "llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/opt/ffmpeg/include -I/usr/include/ffmpeg -I./include -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_e2af7b7_20110721-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pyffmpeg.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/pyffmpeg.o" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: This is probably a ServerFault question.  But try running the Cython self test.  I had problems installing pyffmpeg and gave up when I found that Cython's basic self tasts were failing.

Comment: Great, but I've found nothing on cython selftesting, could you help me out a bit? Thanks for the help!

Comment: That may only apply if you build Cython from its source.  I wanna say it's `python setup.py test` from the Cython source root.

Comment: Ok, I installed it from easy_install, so it probably wouldn't work, although cython appears to be running fine. I got a message from the pyffmpeg devs saying it needs to be updated to the latest cython version because __new__ has been renamed to __cinit__ or something of the like! Thanks anyways!

Comment: So, don't know if anyone's got a great knowledge of cython, but the problem seems to be a variable assignment, namely variable __registered which determines if av components have been registered yet. I fuddled around a bit, but couldn't get it to work. More on the pyffmpeg issue board https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/issues/detail?id=44

Comment: The fix you've put is ok, but i think you must also add "global __registered" just before the "if" test.

Comment: Yep, managed to make it work. Getting stuck up on all sorts of missing libraries. Must be something with macports and normal ffmpeg installation conflicts. Does anyone have any idea where these libraries are supposed to come from? --- pyffmpeg.c:236:35: error: libavutil/mathematics.h: No such file or directory
pyffmpeg.c:237:30: error: libavformat/avio.h: No such file or directory
pyffmpeg.c:238:27: error: libavutil/mem.h: No such file or directory
pyffmpeg.c:240:32: error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
pyffmpeg.c:242:32: error: libswscale/swscale.h: No such file or directory

Comment: libavformat/libavcodec, etc come from http://libav.org/